# Set theory relation: irreflexive and transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Which of the following relations on $T = \{1, 2, 3\}$ is irreflexive and transitive.

1. $\{(2, 1), (2, 3)\}$
2. $\{(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2)\}$
3. $\{(2, 1), (1, 2), (3, 2), (2, 3)\}$
4. $\{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (2, 1), (1, 2)\}$

From my understanding 2 and 4 are excluded because for irreflexitivity $ x \in T $ then $(x, x) \notin R$

but I don't see how either 1 or 3 can be transitive... which I understand as if $(x, y) \in R$ and $(y, z) \in R$ then $(x, z) \in R$

am I missing something here?

Comment: For 1.: that's an *if*. If there are no such pairs $(x, y)$ and $(y, z)$ where $y$ is the first component of one and the second of the other, then transitivity is satisfied by default (or "vacuously", as we say), since there are no counterexamples to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(1)$ is transitive, because the condition of transitivity is vacuously satisfied. There are **no** elements related in such a way for transitivity to *fails*, hence, by default, the relation is transitive.

$(3)$ is not transitive, because $(3, 2), (2, 3) \in R$ but $(3, 3)\notin R$.

Comment: Could use another UV! +1

Comment: I failed to answer. :(

Answer (score 1):

Only one of them is transitive, and vacuously so, since there are no $x,y,z$ such that both $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ are in the relation. The other has a pair $(x,y)$ and a pair $(y,z)$ such that $(x,z)$ is not an element of the relation.