# On transitive relations

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

> Link to similar post:
>   [Set theory relation: irreflexive and transitive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533500/set-theory-relation-irreflexive-and-transitive)

My question is a little bit different from the one above.
My question is why we say that transitivity property is satisfied "by default" or "vacuously" for a relation $R$ in a set $X$ when we are not able to find **any** single pair of  elements in $R$ of the forms $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ where $a,b,c \in X$ so that we can check for transitivity.

I understand that if we said that $R$ is not transitive, then we reach the conclusion from it that $R$ contains elements such that $(a,b), (b,c) \in R$ but $(a,c)\notin R$ which is, of course, not true since it does not contain any pair of elements in $R$ of the forms $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ where $a,b,c \in X$.

But still, doesn't saying that $R$ is transitive imply that it satisfies the condition of transitivity, that is

if  $(a,b), (b,c) \in R$

$\implies (a,c)\in R$

$\forall$  $ a,b,c \in X$      **?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the condition must be satisfied, and also the condition **is satisfied** in this particular case.

Read the condition as:

"for every pair $(a,b),(b,c)\in R$ we must have $(a,c)\in R$"

Is there a pair $(a,b),(b,c)\in R$ for which this is not the case here?

No!

Actually even stronger: we do not even have any pair $(a,b),(b,c)\in R$.

(so there is definitely not a pair $(a,b),(b,c)\in R$ for which it is not true that $(a,c)\in R$)